# Updates() doesn't seem to update the associations

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have the following structs.

```
type Relation struct {
    gorm.Model
    OwnerID      uint          `json:"ownerID"`
    OwnerType    string        `json:"ownerType"`
    Addresses    []Address     `gorm:"polymorphic:Owner;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;" json:"addresses"`
}

type Company struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name     string   `json:"name"`
    Relation Relation `gorm:"polymorphic:Owner;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:CASCADE;" json:"relation"`
}

type Address struct {
    gorm.Model
    OwnerID   uint   `json:"ownerID"`
    OwnerType string `json:"ownerType"`
    Country   string `json:"country"`
    Zip       string `json:"zip"`
    Number    uint   `json:"number,string"`
    Addition  string `json:"addition"`
    Street    string `json:"street"`
    State     string `json:"state"`
    City      string `json:"city"`
}
```

And the following handler

```
func UpdateCompany(db *database.Database) fiber.Handler {
    return func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        id, err := IDFromParams(c)
        if err != nil {
            return c.JSON(responseKit.ParameterMissing())
        }

        update := new(model.Company)
        if err = json.Unmarshal(c.Body(), update); err != nil {
            return c.JSON(responseKit.ParsingError())
        }

        if result := db.Session(&gorm.Session{FullSaveAssociations: true}).Where("id = ?", id).Debug().Updates(update); result.Error != nil {
            return c.JSON(responseKit.RecordUpdateError())
        }

        updated := new(model.Company)
        result := db.Preload("Relation.Addresses").
            Find(updated, id)

        if result.Error != nil {
            return c.JSON(responseKit.RecordReadError())
        }

        return c.JSON(responseKit.RecordUpdatedSuccess(updated))
    }
}
```

I read

https://gorm.io/docs/associations.html

and

https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/3487#issuecomment-698303344

but it does not seem to work.

I use a rest client to call the endpoint with the following JSON

```
{
    "name": "yep",
    "relation": {
        "adresses": [
            {
                "number": "5"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And I parse it into a struct. When I print that struct `update := new(model.Company)` it has the correct data. But when I run the update I get the following output?

```
INSERT INTO "addresses" ("created_at","updated_at","deleted_at","owner_id","owner_type","country","zip","number","addition","street","state","city") VALUES ('2021-01-14 10:48:56.399','2021-01-14 10:48:56.399',NULL,11,'relations','','',5,'','','','') ON CONFLICT ("id") DO UPDATE SET "created_at"="excluded"."created_at","updated_at"="excluded"."updated_at","deleted_at"="excluded"."deleted_at","owner_id"="excluded"."owner_id","owner_type"="excluded"."owner_type","country"="excluded"."country","zip"="excluded"."zip","number"="excluded"."number","addition"="excluded"."addition","street"="excluded"."street","state"="excluded"."state","city"="excluded"."city" RETURNING "id"
INSERT INTO "relations" ("created_at","updated_at","deleted_at","owner_id","owner_type") VALUES ('2021-01-14 10:48:56.399','2021-01-14 10:48:56.399',NULL,0,'companies') ON CONFLICT ("id") DO UPDATE SET "created_at"="excluded"."created_at","updated_at"="excluded"."updated_at","deleted_at"="excluded"."deleted_at","owner_id"="excluded"."owner_id","owner_type"="excluded"."owner_type" RETURNING "id"
UPDATE "companies" SET "updated_at"='2021-01-14 10:48:56.399',"name"='yep' WHERE id = 3
```

So it does inserts for it's relations. But I want it to update the records.

Comment: i think you have to use `&model.Company{}` instead of `model.Company`

Comment: You mean in the Updates()? But that would mean that I'd have to copy over all the fields.Which is not something I would like to do for every update handler. I want it to take all the fields.

Comment: you get all fields which is in `Company` Model

Comment: have you tried `db.Model(model.Company{}).Where("id = ?", id).Updates(*update)`?

Comment: @M_x could you clarify? If id do `.Updated(&model.Company{SomeField1: 1, SomeField2: 2})` It means I have to copy over every value which seems like unnecessary code.

Comment: @EminLaletovic yes I have but sadly it did not work

Comment: no, you have to provide data from postman i think .. not in &model.Company`{}`

Comment: @M_x I am currently providing the data from the rest client which is put into `update := &model.Company{}` which is working like a charm. But using `update := &model.Company{}` in the `.Updates()`  doesn't seem to work. So I think I'm misunderstanding what you are trying to tell me. Could you maybe provide a example as an answer?

Comment: I've updated my answer to address the new detail you've added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Insert statements you see are in fact Upsert statements, you'll notice that after the insert part, they have an ON CONFLICT clause. What that does is update the record if the primary key is already in the table (i.e. there is a key conflict, hence the name). So `Updates` is working as expected.

### BUT!

There is still a problem. As it stands those statements will still result in a new Relation and a new Address being inserted into the database because there will be no primary key conflict. This stems from the fact that you've not entered a primary key for the Relation or the Address row (you'll see that there is no `id` column in the insert).

Rule of thumb:

> Gorm treats structs with a zero primary key as new rows, and inserts them on save.
> Corollary: you can only update structs that have a nonzero primary key.

You might think that you have given a primary key in the `Where` call, but that only applies to the top level struct. When gorm processes the relations, it sees no primary keys and assumes you're wanting to add new relations, not update the existing ones.

If you think about it for a moment, this makes sense: how could gorm know which Relation is currently related to the Company if you don't provide a Relation.ID. The way to know that would be to do a SELECT with the OwnerID and OwnerType first to find out, but this isn't something gorm will do for you (gorm in general tries to be minimalistic and doesn't attempt to find out more info on it's own than what you've given).

One trivial way to tackle this would be to have your API user provide the Relation.ID and Address.IDs in the input, but that's highly inconvenient in this case.

A good pattern I have found to tackle this is to first load the current state of your target root object together with the relevant relations that you want to update, then apply the changes coming from the API user to the struct and relations, then use `Save`. This would save all fields regardless of whether they were changed.

Another option would be to put in the existing IDs of the relations into `update.Relation.ID` and `update.Relation.Addresses[i].ID` from the version you've pulled out of the DB and then calling `Updates` as you've done here.

### Bonus: HasMany has more update challenges

Special care would need to be taken in the case of Addresses because it's a HasMany relation. When calling `Save/Updates` gorm will never delete relations, so when for example you had 3 addresses before and now want to have just two, it will just update two of them and leave the third one hanging about; this is to prevent removal of data by mistake. Instead you have to be explicit about your intention.

What you want to do then is to use Association mode to replace the association, but in the same transaction as where you call `Updates`:

```golang
tx := db.Begin()
// do your thing
err := tx.
    Session(&gorm.Session{FullSaveAssociations: true}).
    Where("id = ?", id).
    Omit("Relation.Addresses")
    Updates(update).
    Error
if err != nil {
    tx.Rollback()
    // handle error
}
// assuming update.Relation.ID is set
err = tx.
    Model(&update.Relation).
    Association("Addresses").
    Replace(&update.Relation.Addresses)
if err != nil {
    tx.Rollback()
    // handle error
}
if err := tx.Commit().Error; err !=  nil {
    tx.Rollback()
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this become very complex if you have deeply nested structs with hasMany relations?

Comment: Absolutely, but it’s hardly a surprise to have complex code when one works with a complex structure and expects fine grained control, I guess. One way around that is to hide the complexity behind a CompanyRepository that takes care of DB persistence at a higher level of abstraction.

Comment: Another thing you might find useful to hide this particular complexity is to use the `BeforeUpdate/BeforeSave` hooks in each parent struct of a HasMany relationship. Those can both change the query, and perform extra queries on the same transaction.

Comment: I ended up using hooks like you suggested and it works like a charm. Thanks again!